# Golang unit testing python function

Tags: python, unit-testing, go

I have an API handler in Golang that calls a python function. How can I mock the response from the python function to avoid dependence of that function running correctly to test the Golang function?

Comment: I would assume that doing this in go is not that different than Python, in which you would use some mocking library like one of these? https://github.com/golang/mock

Comment: What about adding a bool param that indicates whether to call the real Python module.  Then if not, call a function that returns mock results in the same format as the Python module would.  Have your unit tests tell it not to call the real Python module.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your function into a new moc function:

```
func CallPythonFunctionMoc() Result {
    var res Result
    var err error
    res, err = CallPythonFunction()
    if err != nil {
        res = "Moc value"
    }
    return res
```

Edit:

If you do NOT actually want to call the python function just return the moc-value:

```
func CallPythonFunctionMoc() Result {
    res := "Moc value"
    return res
```

Comment: How does this help me unit test? I don't want to actually call the function, I just want to mock the output.

Comment: This helps because if the function returns an error (because the pythonfunction is not ready) the output is mocked.